# обращение к группе пользователей opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Как обратиться к группе пользователей на opencart через short_name? Версия 2.3.0.2.2. Нужно, чтобы колонка в таблице в админке(список заказов) показывалась только для конкретной группе пользователей(с определенным short_name).

Comment: Версия opencart и конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Версия 2.3.0.2.2. Нужно, чтобы колонка в таблице в админке(список заказов) показывалась только для конкретной группе пользователей(с определенным short_name).

Comment: @php777 Под вопросом есть кнопка "править". Добавьляйте эти, та и впринципе все важные детали в текст вопроса. Так будет проще его воспринимать и не бегать за доп информацией в комменты.